# Swift 4: When a user clicks on a UiButton how do I grab the string that is selected in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

Question: I am trying to know which town someone selected when they clicked on a UIButton. When the user clicks on the UIButton I want to be able to know the "name" of which townName the user selected. How can I do this? I was able to pass the indexPath.row successfully but I am not sure how to pass the name of the town the user selected. This is my code below. Would love any help on this!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TownCell
    let name = townName[indexPath.row].name
    let regionId = townName[indexPath.row].region_code

    cell.townLabel.text = "\(name), \(regionId)"

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    print(townName[indexPath.row].name)
    print(townName[indexPath.row].region_code)
    return cell
}


    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = greenCTAColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.setTitle("select", for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("selected", for: .selected)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
        button.tintColor = .clear
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 16)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func selectedAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentCellNumber = sender.tag
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if button.isSelected {
                button.isSelected = false
                button.backgroundColor = greenCTAColor
                print("User unselected cell number: \(currentCellNumber!)")
            } else {
                button.isSelected = true
                button.backgroundColor = blueCTAColor
                print("User selected cell number: \(currentCellNumber!)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does currentCellNumber is printing in log?

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun yes it does by doing the IndexPath.row

Comment: I am talking about your selectedAction function

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun yes when I click on the UIButton it shows me what row number I clicked on

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun this wont work because the "currentCellNumber" is only attached to the sender.tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170716/discussion-between-kazi-abdullah-al-mamun-and-box-house).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the town from the townName array based on the button tag you set in collection view, and is your action method is calling? if its calling below will work

```
@objc func selectedAction(sender: UIButton) {
        let currentCellNumber = sender.tag
        if button.isSelected {
            button.isSelected = false
            button.backgroundColor = greenCTAColor
            print("User unselected cell number: \(currentCellNumber!)")
        } else {
            button.isSelected = true
            button.backgroundColor = blueCTAColor
            print("User selected cell number: \(currentCellNumber!)")
        }

        let town = townName[currentCellNumber]
        print(town.name)
    }
```

In cellForItemAt 
add action to the button for that cell

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I always create button and action in the collectionViewCell class and than use delegate patten to pass around data. but as you have created action in the same controller above will work, as action is set to self it will call  selectedAction.

Comment: Thanks! I currently have this in two different classes. So since I have it in two different classes, the above isn't working. How can I fix that to make it work?

Comment: I am getting this --> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: In collection view there is no row only items, change it to item, and put breakpoint and check what value you are getting for currentCellNumber

Comment: Where is your cell button? how you accessing cell.button?

Comment: My cell button is in a different class and I am accessing the uibutton by putting cell.button.tag = indexPath.item

Comment: then in my func selectedation() I am calling let currentCellNumber = sender.tag to get what row the cell is in

Comment: so you added the line "cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedAction), for: .touchUpInside)" below cell.button.tag = indexPath.item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170720/discussion-between-box-house-and-iraniya-naynesh).

Comment: Were you able to show me how to do a delegate and the other thing your talking about? Looking forward to seeing it!